# EKEvent Adding event to day with a ical event

Tags: ios, xcode, events, calendar, ekevent

I'm using the following code to add event to iphone's calendar,

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
event.title = @"title";
event.startDate = [NSDate date];
event.endDate = somedate;
[event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
[eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
```

And to access the events I use,

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
NSPredicate *predicate = [eventStore predicateForEventsWithStartDate:startDate endDate:endDate calendars:nil];     
NSArray *eventsOfTheMonth = [eventStore eventsMatchingPredicate:predicate];

NSMutableArray *tempEKEvents = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:[eventsOfTheMonth count]];

for (EKEvent *event in eventsOfTheMonth) {

        [tempEKEvents addObject:event];

    }

}
```

For some reason when I want to add a new event to a day that already has an event added by the iCal, the event won't add. But it will add the event to any other day, even to the ones that have more than one events that are added through my app.

Comment: Is there anything in `err` when it fails?

Comment: no, it doesn't fail or give any error. it just doesn't add the event.

Comment: Actually, `saveEvent:span:error` returns a boolean indicating success or failure. What does that report?

Comment: What's backing this calendar? Is it a CalDav/Exchange/etc or is it just local?

Comment: I'm not sure, but it's a birthday event added to ical

Comment: actually it has the same behavior with other events added to ical other than birthdays too.